# Idiom for people complaining excessively

Tags: idioms

What is an idiom applicable when someone is voluntarily participating in an action, and complaining excessively? I thought of using "don't let the door hit you on the way out", but I don't want to tell the person to leave, just want to say something along the lines of "nobody is holding you here"?

Comment: cry wolf - perhaps

Answer (score 3):

**If you can't stand the heat, get out of the kitchen.**
[Phrasefinder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/get-out-of-the-kitchen.html)

> Don't persist with a task if the pressure of it is too much for you.
>   The implication being that, if you can't cope, you should leave the
>   work to someone who can.

But sometimes a person, especially one who never seems to be satisfied, deserves a sarcastic epithet.

> You're a right *[ray of sunshine](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+ray+of+sunshine)*.
>   You're a [bundle of joy](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bundle+of+joy),
>   this morning. Aren't you?
>   Don't tell me. You must be the *[glass is half full](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glass-half-full)* kind of person.

If the person still doesn't get it, just tell him or her straight:

> Has anyone ever told you: "You're a miserable [so and so](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/so+and+so)"?
>   Can you stop acting like a [crybaby](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crybaby) for once?
>   Could you keep your [whinging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whinge) to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**Whining**

> "Quit your *whining*."

**Kvetch**

> "Can I help or did you just want to *kvetch*?"

Answer (score 0):

"What's keeping you here?"/ "What's stopping you from leaving?"/ "Who's making you do this?"/ "Who asked you to do this?"

Not exactly idiomatic expressions, but these are what I'd imagine saying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask politely?  
For example:

> "I'm sorry, but if you're not doing.... I think it's not helpful for you to stay."

Answer (score 0):

[Nattering nabob of negativism](http://rpayne.blogspot.com/2005/11/nattering-nabob-of-negativism.html)

> In a speech in San Diego in 1970, then Vice President Spiro Agnew used the phrase "nattering nabobs of negativism" to describe supposed intellectuals who attacked American policy....
>
> the phrase does paint an interesting although unpleasant word picture of a self-important person nagging and criticizing everyone else.